# GTK3 Dialog in Python, "enter key" on a Gtk.Entry should trigger the OK Button

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3

I have following code written in Python with Gtk3.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class DialogTaskDescription(Gtk.Dialog):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, "Create ToDo.txt Entry", 0, 0,
            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
             Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

        self.set_default_size(150, 100)

        hbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=6)

        self.label = Gtk.Label("Task Description:")
        self.taskDescription = Gtk.Entry()
        hbox.pack_start(self.label, False, True, 0)
        hbox.pack_start(self.taskDescription, True, True, 0)

        box = self.get_content_area()
        box.add(hbox)
        self.show_all()

    def getTaskDescription(self):
        return self.taskDescription.get_text()

class TaskDescription:

    def __init__(self):
        self.dialog = DialogTaskDescription()

    def getTaskDescription(self):
        response = self.dialog.run()
        taskDescription = ''

        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            taskDescription = self.dialog.getTaskDescription()

        self.dialog.destroy()

        return taskDescription
```

Now I would like to trigger a click on the OK-button if the user press the enter key on the "taskDescription" entry field. Any idea how I could do this? Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

I found a solution... Not sure if it is the way it should be done, but this works:

I added following lines to the init method of DialogTaskDescription():

```
# enter key should trigger the default action
self.taskDescription.set_activates_default(True)

# make OK button the default
okButton = self.get_widget_for_response(response_id=Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
okButton.set_can_default(True)
okButton.grab_default()
```

Comment: Yes, that's the way to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution... Not sure if it is the way it should be done, but this works:

I added following lines to the init method of DialogTaskDescription():

```
# enter key should trigger the default action
self.taskDescription.set_activates_default(True)

# make OK button the default
okButton = self.get_widget_for_response(response_id=Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
okButton.set_can_default(True)
okButton.grab_default()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another example for an Gtk3 Dialog asking for some SpinButton value:

```
class Days_Back:

    def __init__(self):
        self.days = self.days_back()

    def days_back(self, title="Days Back", max_number=10):
        __title__ = title

        flags = Gtk.DialogFlags.MODAL
        dialog = Gtk.Dialog(title=__title__,
                           flags=flags,
                           buttons=(Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
                           Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

        dialog.set_default_response(Gtk.ResponseType.OK)

        box = dialog.get_content_area()
        adjustment = Gtk.Adjustment(1, 1, max_number, 1, 5, 0)
        spin_button = Gtk.SpinButton(adjustment=adjustment, climb_rate=1, digits=0)
        spin_button.show()
        spin_button.set_activates_default(True)
        box.add(spin_button)

        response = dialog.run()
        dialog.destroy()

        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            logging.debug("you choosed Gtk.ResponseType.OK")
            return spin_button.get_value_as_int()
        else:
            exit(response)
```